# Can a Terminal window be resized with a Terminal command?

Tags: terminal

So that I could resize the window to a certain size from within Terminal.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Yes. Terminal supports escape sequences for manipulating windows, including the size and position, layering, and minimizing. Dimensions can be expressed in pixels or characters. See [Xterm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) for details (search for “Window manipulation”; if you’re not familiar with the notation, “CSI” stands for “Control Sequence Introducer”, which is `ESC [`).

For example, this shell command will set the window to 100x50 characters:

```
printf '\e[8;50;100t'
```

Minimize the window for a few seconds, then restore it:

```
printf '\e[2t' && sleep 3 && printf '\e[1t'
```

Move the window to the top/left corner of the display:

```
printf '\e[3;0;0t'
```

Zoom the window:

```
printf '\e[9;1t'
```

Bring the window to the front (without changing keyboard focus):

```
printf '\e[5t'
```

### Enabling the Control Sequences in Terminal Emulators

Some terminal emulators ignore these control sequences by default and require configuration to enable them.

To enable these in *XTerm*, set the following resource to true:

> **allowWindowOps**

To enable these in *iTerm2*, deselect the following preference:

> **Preferences > Profiles > [profile] > Terminal > Disable session-initiated window resizing**

Comment: This is just perfect!

Comment: From now on you are my god!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Yosemite with iterm2

Comment: This works great but it seems Terminal does not accept resizings that would make the window only partially visible on the screen. I just tried printf '\e[8;100;100t' and this truncated to 79x100, just what could be fit. My problem is that I need to bypass the mouse just for this case of enlarging Terminal beyond the screen limits ...

Comment: @phs Why do you need the window to be larger than the screen?

Comment: There are many reasons. E.g. to not fold long lines. Or not have ncurses-based legacy code complain that the window is too small. Or you want to increase font size with 'Cmd +' and not change number of lines. Or .. Now, can Terminal be told to resize beyond screen limits?

Comment: @phs Not via the escape sequences or by increasing the font size. Only the user resizing the window can do that. If you need to do that, consider filing a bug report: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: @phs I should have asked a more specific question: why do you need to resize the window larger than the screen via escape sequences? Note that you should be able to use application scripting (e.g., using AppleScript) to layout windows, especially if you don't need to do it via escape sequences sent to the terminal through the tty device.

Comment: I already explained why the question is legit. I am happy with an answer like 'sorry Terminal.app can't do that'

Comment: @phs I'm not questioning the legitimacy of the question, nor am I saying that Terminal can't do that. I'm asking for more detail to understand the requirements for your use-case.

Comment: This also works with iTerm2.

Comment: Does not work in my Terminal (macOS 10.14, Mojave).

Comment: @Gabriel That’s not enough information to go on. You should probably create another Q&A question detailing exactly what you did and what result you got.

Comment: I tried this command in Terminal:
`% printf '\e[8;50;100t'`

This is what I get on the command line (nothing else happens)
`e[8;50;100t%`

Since its not an XTerm, there are no configurations regarding escape sequences.

However, the osascript command mentioned below works fine; just put it in a bash script.

Comment: @Gabriel create another Q&A asking how to get it to work, detailing exactly what you did, what you expected to happen as a result, and what result you got. Include the OS version. When I Copy and Paste the command from your comment, it works fine for me: it resizes the window to 100x50.

Comment: Awesome answer!

Comment: I've been using the escape codes for setting 132 columns and 80 columns for years (starting from actual physical ANSI terminals!), but I had never seen this.  What a revelation.

Answer (score 15):

Use `/usr/X11/bin/resize`.

`resize -s 30 80` will give you 30 rows and 80 columns.

`resize -s 30 0` will give you 30 rows and full columns.

`resize -s 0 80` will give you full rows and 80 columns.

Comment: This solution is not limited to MacOS. It is terminal-based, so it should work on all terminals. I use this to resize PuTTY windows on Windows running bash shells with TERM=xterm.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Yosemite in iterm2.

Comment: This works for me with Apple Terminal but not iTerm2. However, sending the escape sequence \e[8;24;80t works with both.

Comment: Really? I can't seem to get that sequence (\e[8;24;80t) to work under iTerm2 (v3.1.5).

Comment: @KrishenGreenwell Refer to the iTerm2 documentation. By default it ignores these control sequences. There’s a preference to control whether they are ignored.

Comment: This solution used to work, but I think, the X11 commands are gone. Maybe, they can be installed by installing X11, but I don't want to install X11 just to have the resize command.

Comment: Can confirm that this solution unfortunately doesn't work on MacOS Ventura 13.0

Answer (score 10):

You could always use AppleScript:

```
setwidth() { osascript -e "tell app \"Terminal\" to tell window 1
set b to bounds
set item 3 of b to (item 1 of b) + $1
set bounds to b
end"; }
```

Comment: This only works for the currently active terminal window/tab. For this to reliably work, get the current tty device pathname and locate the terminal tab that matches.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/a/576357

Answer (score 2):

My apologies for necro-reviving an old question, but I thought this answer might be useful for others.

From [tedsmith3rd](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/terminal-command-to-move-terminal-window.229161/), here's a **bash** function to move a Terminal window.  The magic of terminal command sequences.

```
function bumpNjump() {
  local xDimension="" yDimension="" width="" height="" OPTIND

  while getopts 'x:y:w:h:' thisArg
  do
     case "${thisArg}" in
        x) xDimension="${OPTARG}" ;;
        y) yDimension="${OPTARG}" ;;
        w) width="${OPTARG}" ;;
        h) height="${OPTARG}" ;;
     esac
  done

  if [ -n "${width}" -a -n "${height}" ]
  then
     printf '\e[4;'${height}';'${width}'t';
  fi

  if [ -n "${xDimension}" -a -n "${yDimension}" ]
  then
     printf '\e[3;'${xDimension}';'${yDimension}'t'
  fi
}
```

Combine that with this **termsize.bash** script to get the current geometry, and you have an easy way to control your Terminal window.

```
#!/bin/bash
# based on a script from http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html
exec < /dev/tty
oldstty=$(stty -g)
stty raw -echo min 0

printf "\e[13t" > /dev/tty
IFS=';' read -r -d t -a pos

xpos=${pos[1]}
ypos=${pos[2]}

# Window (including chrome) size in pixels
printf "\e[14;2t" > /dev/tty
IFS=';' read -r -d t -a size

hsize=${size[1]}
wsize=${size[2]}

stty $oldstty

echo "bumpNjump -x $xpos -y $ypos -h $hsize -w $wsize"
```

Comment: This looks useful, though doesn't work for me on MacOS 10.5.6 - it prints out the control characters:

`bumpNjump -x 10 -y 20 -w 800 -h 300`

`\E[4;300;800t\E[3;10;20t`

Does it work for you?

Comment: Ah - it works in iTerm if you disable the option shown in an earlier answer:


To enable these in iTerm2, deselect the following preference:

Preferences > Profiles > [profile] > Terminal > Disable session-initiated window resizing

Answer (score -3):

Actually you know, moving an resizing windows with a mouse is horribly slow.

I've been using this app [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/index.html) for a very long time now. It basically resizes any application window by using your keyboard command.

You can do the following (my custom keyboard commands below):

- make the window full screen (<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>)
- move a window 1/2 screen size to the left or right (<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> )
- move a window 1/4 screen size to any corner (<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>)
- move windows between screens
- move windows between spaces

I think this might do the trick and also help with other window management.

Comment: Although useful, this doesn't address the question the questioner asked.